# Error while importing .sql file into Cloud SQL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have uploaded a .sql file that I've exported via phpMyAdmin to Google Cloud Storage. When I attempt to import the file to Cloud SQL I get this error:

> mysql_query No database selected (CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `auction_login` ( `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `username` varchar(12) NOT NULL, `password` varchar(18) NOT NULL, `created_date` date NOT NULL, `created_time` time NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2)

Comment: Unless there is a good reason for the `latin1`, I'd recommend you use `utf8` these days.

Answer (score 0):

You should either add "use *name of your database*;" 
e.g.:

```
use test;
```

to the top of your script, provided "test" is the name of your database.
Substitute that with the name of your database.

or set the default database by editing your connection properties, provided you are using MySQL Workbench or similar.

Comment: You might need to create the database first. Try adding a CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test;  statement first.